# insert numeric data values into oracle data table using oracle bulk copy

Tags: c#, excel, bulkinsert

I am fetching a data from excel into a data table using oledb connection.

the values in the data table as follows:

xxxx 22

yyyy 23

zzzz 24

but when i m trying to write it into oracle table using oracle bulkcopy

the values are as follows:

xxxx 0

yyyy 0

zzzz 0

where as the same working fine for csv and other text files.

```
using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(StaticClass.DestConnectionString))

{
  con.Open();
  using (OracleBulkCopy oleBulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(con))
     {
        oleBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Tbl_Test;
        oleBulkCopy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
        oleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);                               
     }

}
```

Table structure is
Name varchar(50),
Age  varchar(50)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What command are you sending in oracle bulk copy. Please post here. Also, post the schema of the table you are using.

Comment: Is there a question here ? You should really say HOW you are doing this ...